# Set Python environment variable inside windows service

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, windows-services

I would like to set a environment variable from inside a window service. My first trial was to use the os.environ['OPENSSL_CONF']=LIB_DIR. This works from cmd shell like if i do run as someexe.exe launch(this is the our code argument), but when I put it inside the body of a service and then if i run someexe.exe install it simply do nothing. Enviroment variable won't set at all. I have installed openssl 3.0.8 and enabled FIPS. Also this code works for other platforms except for Windows.

Below is the sample code

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    LIB_DIR = INSTALLEDDIR
os.environ['OPENSSL_CONF'] = LIB_DIR
```

Please help me to understand what is missing from the windows service side.